# Simple projectile motion question that I can't figure out

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

[image]

My initial choice was B, but apparently that should have been immediately eliminated. I simply found the root of the values squared. I know that horizontal motion would be constant velocity, and vertical would be constant acceleration. The correct answer is C.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: @KyleKanos OP has stated in previous answers that these problems aren't homework problems, so this one probably isn't one either.

Comment: @Trifork: OP can continue to call it not homework all they want, but doing so is wrong because it is homework as the site defines it. If you (or he) had bothered to read the first link I provided, you would see this **is** a homework problem and, as such, is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @KyleKanos ok, sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remember how vertical and horizontal components of velocity act independently? If start out with velocity $v_0$ with launch angle $\theta$ then we have $v_{h_0} = v_0 cos(\theta)$ and $v_{v_0} = v_0 sin(\theta)$. Note that the horizontal component doesn't change during flight because no force is acting horizontally on the object (if we neglect air resistance). The vertical component, however, undergoes deceleration $g$ due to gravity, so we have $v_h(t) = v_0 cos(\theta)$ and $v_v(t) = v_0sin(\theta) - gt$.

We know that $v_h(2) = 39.2$ and $v_v(2) = 19.6$ from the diagram, so we have the equations:

$$ v_0 cos(\theta) = 39.2 $$

and

$$ v_0 sin(\theta) - 2g = 19.6 $$

To solve for $v_0$, square the first equation, and square the second equation after adding $2g$ to both sides. Then add the two equations to get:

$$ v_0^2 cos^2(\theta) + v_0^2 sin^2(\theta) = 39.2^2 + (19.6 + 2g)^2$$
$$ v_0^2 = 3073.28 $$

So $v_0 = 55.4$ m/s. Then plug in this value of $v_0$ into the first equation to obtain

$$\theta = cos^{-1} (\frac{39.2}{v_0}) = 45^{\circ}$$

Note that neither answer B nor D could be correct because if $\theta = 30^{\circ}$, then either (1) $v_{h_0} = 2v_{v_0}$ or (2) $v_{v_0} = 2v_{h_0}$ (think of a 30-60-90 triangle). Situation (1) can't work because we know that $v_v(2) \ne v_{v_0}$ (unless the object is just about to land, which can't be happening because it would then be falling, but $v_v(2) > 0$). Situation (2) can't work because the resulting magnitude would be greater than any of the answers suggest since $\sqrt{32.9^2 + (2 \times 39.2)^2} > 2 \times 39.2 > 55.4$.

Comment: By the way, I think @Alfred Centauri's answer is more correct and complete than mine.

Answer (score 1):

> I simply found the root of the values squared.

That calculation gives you the speed at $t = 2\; \mathrm{s}$, not the launch speed.

But you know the launch speed must be greater since the vertical velocity, while still positive, has been *decreasing* since the launch.

This leaves only answers (C) and (D).

In 2 seconds, the vertical velocity must have changed by

$$\Delta v_V = -9.81\; \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}} \cdot 2\; \mathrm{s}=-19.62  \mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$$

The correct answer should now be obvious.

Comment: In fairness, the question could be clearer; *finding* the velocity at two seconds elapsed time *from* the diagram is not the same as having the velocity at two seconds *displayed* in the diagram...